# Defining a custom cross referencing style

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, macros

I want my cross reference links to look like:

```
Chapter X: Chapter Title
```

To achieve that I have created the following command:

```
\newcommand{\fancyref}[1]{\autoref{#1}: \nameref{#1}}
```

The problem is that the `:` character is not part of the generated hyperlink.

Could someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Warning I get when compiling Leo Liu's example:

```
LaTeX Warning: Reference `*' on page 1 undefined on input line 10.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2009/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./example.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
\hyperref[label]{\autoref*{label}: \nameref*{label}}
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref,nameref}
\newcommand\myref[1]{%
  \hyperref[#1]{\autoref*{#1}: \nameref*{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\section{Foo}
\label{sec:foo}

\myref{sec:foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It didn't quite work for me. It is giving fata errors. I think the problem is the `*` how can I have the `*` in a newcommand definition?

Comment: @Tiago: I add a full example works for me. Check your code if there is something wrong. The `*` avoids a hyper link here.

Comment: Perhaps we have different versions, but when i compile your example I get the error in my question above.

Comment: Today I have updated my TeX distribution. I can confirm that this now works for me.